# Proving that Brownian Motion Cubed is Martingale

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation, martingales

Prove that ... is martingale..

Comment: Theoretically there is no difference between the square and the cube. You onIy need  the formula $(x-y)^{3}=x^{3}-3x^{2}y+3xy^{2}-y^{3}$. You should try to work this out yourself since it looks like a homework problem.

Comment: I understand how to do the square without the integral term - I'm just not sure how to deal with the integral. Would you provide a little more clarity in your response, it's a practice exam question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $E(\int_0^{t+s} W(u)du|\mathcal F_t)=\int_0^{t} W(u)du+E(\int_t^{t+s} [(W(u)-W(t))+W(t)]du|\mathcal F_t)$. The second term is just $sW(t)$ becasue $E(\int_t^{t+s} [(W(u)-W(t))]du=0$ by independence.

Comment: So is it fair to say that $M(t) = W^3(t)-3\int_0^tW(u) du = W^3(t)-3tW(t)$ ?